# Need help in figuring out a logic in for loop

Tags: python

Can someone help me in figuring out how to get the beow mentioned pattern for a name.

input:

```
'Jessika Polo'
```

output:

```
J
es
sik
a Po
lo
```

increments by one in every row including whitespaces. im hoping to solve this with a for loop but i cant find the logic.

Answer (score 1):

This is easiest with a `while`. Keep two variables, `i` and `l`, that store the start of the current slice and the length of the current slice. Whilst `i` is less than the length of the string, print the slice from `i` to `i+l`, then increment `i` by `l` and `l` by `1`.

```
s = 'Jessika Polo'
l = 1
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    print(s[i:i+l])
    i += l
    l += 1
```

---

Output:

```
J
es
sik
a Po
lo
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and can we do the same using for loop?

Comment: Well you could work out a formula for the general case. I.e. given a string, how many of these increasing-length substrings will it yield. I suspect it&#39;ll be the inverse of the formula for the triangle numbers... Once you have that, you can have a for loop that iterates over the lengths and slices from the calculated start onwards by that length